# VueJs Getting emit value from a past event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am emitting an event using an eventBus. I am looking to get the value from this on another component. At the moment, this triggers when something is selected, however, I want to be able to get the data from a Past event. For example, I have emitted the value when selecting an item. In another component, I wish to use this value again.

Here is the code to send the event:

```
    clientId(client) {
      eventBus.$emit("selected", client);
    },
```

In the component, I am receiving it like this:

```
created() {
    eventBus.$on("selected", index => this.client(index));
  },
```

However it is not working for a past event.

I would like this to update a data value in a different component so that i can use the value.

How can I get the value of a past event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a store for preserving data, simply inside your event bus update the store and then you can use a `getter` to retrieve the data from the store in any component. If you are not familiar take a look at the vuex docs.